# How can do auto-indent upon newline in VS Code like this

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In this situation,

[image]

When I add newline at `if (level >= curr_log_level)`,
at this setting,

[image]

It becomes

[image]

If I try other `Editor: Auto Indent` preferences, (keep, brackets, advanced, full), all the four settings give:

[image]

I don't want this either, what I want is:

[image]

I tried many different settings that VS Code offers,
but I couldn't find something that does what I want to do exactly.
CLion provided such formatting, but its debugging is too slow so I'm switching to VS Code.

1. Is there such formatting option?
2. If not, how can I customize formatting?

Comment: What happens if you put an empty line in-between the function signature and your `if` statement?

Comment: @Dai For "none" setting, the empty line has no indentation. ```if``` statement follows the indentation of the empty line (so no indentation). For other settings, the empty line has the same indentation with ```Args&&...```, and ```if``` statement follows the same

Comment: tbh, use some auto-format extension like prettier. Instead of spending times for this. use your time for your coding/algorithms. // this is comment, not answer